# BLE advertising packet formation using nordic stack

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

I am working on A BLE beacon application to advertise data.
I am using nordic nrf52 Development kit and nordic sdk s132.
I am starting from the beacon exapmle provided by nordic.
My question is how is the packet format of the message generated by that example:
because as I could see from the code the only thing I am changing as a user the the manufacturer specific data field and as far as I know a BLE packet has this format [image]
But I do not see any function to calculate the CRC and In the included driver files I do not see any security related files 
Should I add these by myself and if so I need to know what is exactly handled by the nordic stack and is that I should add myself

Comment: have you see this?  ... https://electronut.in/bluey-beacon/